# How to deploy Asp.Net Core using .net Framework application to IIS

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core

I have developed an application with Asp.net Core using the .net Framework. When I published my project to the Local folder. The files which got created appear like the image below:

[image]

Is this the expected output or am I doing something wrong?

If this is correct, how can I deploy my application to IIS?

Comment: Do you want to just run it locally or host it on a server? In the first case you could just do dotnet run --environment <environment_name>. This will run it with Kestrel by deffault. In the second case I would refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis.

Answer (score 0):

I referred my site path to wwwroot folder in my server. It is working fine
Thanks